# What's the best GR book for recreational study?

Tags: general-relativity, soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I currently have four books.

1. Hartle
2. Schutz
3. Cheng
4. Carroll (lecture notes)

Which one is best for me to read easily? (especially, for foreigners)

Or Do you guys can give good recommendations that are written with easy english?

Comment: Are you trying to learn GR to do research in it, or are you just an interested amateur? I ask because I think Schutz is best for the interested amateur but not so good if you plan to do research.

Comment: I really liked Relativity, Gravitation and Cosmology by Cheng. Also have a look at Zee, A.: Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell, which is a truly amazing introduction

Comment: John/ I'm doing just for fun. I have no plan to do it professionally. Thanks for recommendation. Tim/ Thanks. I will try to look over

Comment: Jacob, I learned (bits of) GR for fun as well and I found the Schutz book to be ideal because it concentrates on concepts rather than the detail. There are professional general relativists hereabouts that hate it for exactly the same reason :-) Have fun, but don't underestimate the amount of work required!

Comment: The linked question specifically requires: *Mathematically rigorous preferred!*. It transpires from the comments that the book request here is for the recreational studiers of GR (yes, we do exist :-) and I think that's a very different question with very different answers. I think the question should be reopened, and possibly edited to make clear it is for recreational study.

Comment: Ah, the gold badge apparently allows me to unilaterally reopen GR tagged questions as well. Sorry David, I didn't realise that would happen. If you want to close the question again I won't vote to reopen.

Comment: I second Tim's recommendation of Zee's book. He manages to get through an amazing amount of material without using really any rigorous mathematics at all. The book was written with self-study in mind, as explained in the prologue. Although, I've always felt he doesn't teach enough group theory for the reader to fully appreciate some sections in the book.